# Streatch the inner div inside td to span the height of td

Tags: html, css

I have dynamic text content inside  all first  tds. So the trs and tds get expanded automatically. Now for all second tds there is div with background image and dont have any text inside. I need this divs with background image to be expanded or collapsed automatically along with the cells in table so that the red image will span over the height of each cell. Any way to do this purely with css as I dont want to introduce script here?    [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mailtoshebin/Z2Xhh/6/)

```
       <table border="1">
         <tr>
              <td> 
                  This content makes the trs and tds to expand/contract horizontally   automatically
             </td>
              <td>
                  <div class="img"></div>
             </td>
        </tr>
             <tr>
              <td>
                     xyz
             </td>
              <td>
                                  All  divs inside second tds should get expanded automatically which is not happening
             </td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

CSS

```
 td
{
 width:200px
}
.img{
    width:30px;
    height:40px;

background: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABMAAAAXCAIAAABmo+ONAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAAAJcEhZcwAADsMAAA7DAcdvqGQAAAApSURBVDhPY3gro0IG+v///6hOvGhUJyE0qpMQGtVJCFGmE4jJAf//AwBnlUxAq2HzYQAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==) no-repeat;}
```

Comment: can you post the css and the image size?

Comment: I see this http://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/800x600q90/59/mitj.png

Answer (score 0):

Just set background for that td with 100% width and height.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mttSA/

```
.empty{
background: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABMAAAAXCAIAAABmo+ONAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAAAJcEhZcwAADsMAAA7DAcdvqGQAAAApSURBVDhPY3gro0IG+v///6hOvGhUJyE0qpMQGtVJCFGmE4jJAf//AwBnlUxAq2HzYQAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==) no-repeat;
background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

HTML:

```
<td class="empty">

</td>
```

Comment: I want 20% of the td width to be occupied by the image so I am using div  is there any other way using the div itself as there are few other img contents coming inside second tds?

Comment: @ShebinMathew [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/mttSA/1/) You need to set a height for the TD or we cannot use the `div` without setting an height.

Comment: So add just padding for your td..?? or create new table in that cell with two cols http://jsfiddle.net/acK4e/